# Spark: Java API filter() shows nothing, result different from spark-shell

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe that I read from parquet.

I want to filter all rows with value of column `DATE` equals to "2019".

When I do this using spark-shell,

```
df.filter("DATE = '2019'").show()
```

it shows all rows so no problem. But when I use Spark Java API:

```
df.filter("DATE = '2019'").count()
```

it shows 0. How is that possible ? I have tested in two cases I have `df.count()` equals to 50 so the problem should be with the filter

Answer (score 1):

As indicated on the Spark documentation [Column.equalTo](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#equalTo(java.lang.Object)) :

**Scala :**

```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

   df.filter( col("DATE") === "2019" ) 
   // === equivalent to equalTo : 
   df.filter( col("DATE").equalTo("2019") );
```

**Java :**

```
   import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

   df.filter( col("DATE").equalTo("2019") );
```

Otherwise you can use the SQL syntax that works in Java and Scala :

```
    df.filter(" DATE = '2019' ");
```